# IOS Different Bundle and Different Country Region app but Use Same Name

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I want to create two iPhone app with different Bundle Ids, and also one App to be available for Canada only and another app to be available for all countries except Canada.

Is that possible and can I use the same name for both applications (knowing that their SKU, primary language and country/regions will be different)?